# Защита каналов discord.js помогите

Tags: node.js, discord-api

Решил сделать защиту каналов в боте то есть если человек с административной ролью удалил канал то с него снимается роль.

```js
 .on('channelDelete', async (message) => {

    const member = message.mentions.members.first();
    const allowedRoles = Util.getProp('administration')
    if (!member.roles.some(r => allowedRoles.includes(r.id))) return;

        member.removeRole(allowedRoles)
        //members undefined
})
```

Comment: Судя по задумке... вы хотите удалить права администратора у пользователя в группе которой не существует по причине ее удаления? Я думаю вам стоит переформулировать ваш вопрос, добавить больше информации об ошибке и подробно описать принцип действия. Для большинства случаев для защиты канала нужно правильно настроить роли

Comment: Заранее скажу вам что отправка сообщений, назначение ролей и прочие действия связанные с пользователями дискорда можно производить только если у бота и у пользователя есть общие каналы